# How to add a raw itinerary with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I using leaflet.
With it I'm displaying two different map : one is with open street map, the other is from ign geoportal.

How to add a raw itinerary with Leaflet ?

I expect this itinerary to be displayed on both map.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two maps you should add the itineray to each map

```
var map1 = L.map('map1', {
  center: [51.505, -0.09],
  zoom: 13
}),
  map2 = L.map('map2', {
  center: [51.505, -0.09],
  zoom: 13
}),
  latlngs = 'Your latlngs array',
  itinerary = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'red'});
  map1.addLayer(itinerary);
  map2.addLayer(itinerary);
```

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline